# Android : Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android

Im confusing about this error 
i start activity but in different package. 
i have search in Google but i'm still confuse. 
i have differen package..

main activity in com.android.studentfinancial

and the login in com.android.studentfinancial.view

here's my main activity

```
package com.android.studentfinancial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StudentFinancialActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent("login.intent.action.Launch"));
    }
}
```

and here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.studentfinancial" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".StudentFinancialActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".view.Login" 
            android:label="User Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="login.intent.action.Launch"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here's the logCat Output

`01-22 21:08:25.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1672): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.studentfinancial/com.android.studentfinancial.StudentFinancialActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.studentfinancial.StudentFinancialActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.android.studentfinancial-1.apk]`

can you help me.??

Answer (score 3):

Your start activity syntax should be like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I just looked at your code again, you have wrong activity name in startActivity. As Basbous said, you need to use complete path to activity name startActivity(new Intent("com.android.stundentfinancial.view.Login"));

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StudentFinancialActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent("com.android.stundentfinancial.view.Login"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Different error : `01-22 22:34:42.826: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.studentfinancial.view.Login }`

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me the cause of the issue was creating a Configuration object (to get device orientation) outside of OnCreate(). It worked fine once I moved the variable inside OnCreate().